# threadpool execution code but no option for shutdown in IDE content assist

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to execute the concurrent.Execute threadpool in an application that assigns parameters to each thread. What I have found in the processing is that it seems more threads are being created than expected. Also no option for the shutdown is available. Perhaps the code below will better illustrate the issue?

This is the method that each thread eventually gets to and the Arraylist is created in the previous method. The threads are created as follows:

```
 Executor executor = 
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
     for (final String server : serverList) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
                while 
                (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        ...


  retrieveMetrics(filterItem,pserver,assignedServer,
      Bean);
```

At the end of the while loop I tried to implement executor.shutdown() but it is not a defined method. Also is my implementation above correct to actually only allow a limited number of threads to be created. Appreciate advice and responses here.

EDIT:

[image: no shutdown method]

I am unable to use shutdown() for some reason.

EDIT 2:

[image: thread count]

Comment: You have to use  executor.shutdown() after the for loop not after while loop. Check and let us know.

Comment: Thanks for responding but see edit above; shutdown() option not available.

Comment: You shutdown ExecutorServices, not Executors

Comment: ah, ok let me try that.

Comment: glad you could fix it : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use below

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
```

instead of

```
Executor executor =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
```

Comment: thank you. Appreciate it. Will try this. Also thank you to Aran as well

Comment: I have one more question: I see the number of thread running is not actually the number declared as threadcount? see edit above please.

Comment: You can see how many threads are running in visualVM. VisualVM is available inside JDK installation.

Comment: ah ok I see that threadpoolexecutor threads are 3 vs other threads